# Geoserver WMS - CORS enabled in web.xml - still error

Tags: geoserver, wms, cors, jetty

I have tried both geoserver 2.12.5 and 2.13.2 with CORS enabled and on both i get an "Invalid CORS request" when accessing WMS from an external webapp.

steps  :

1. install geoserver, port 8095, i have tried both Linux and Windows
2. enable CORS in web.xml
3. restart
4. access WMS from an angular app that runs on 9000 -> CORS Error
5. the same call in a separate tab is getting a json response with  the expected data

Accessing it through geoserver "preview layers" is working, 
(also the GetFeatureInfo-call as **there** it is not a CORS-call)

I am using the sample layer nurc:Img_Sample

Using a different IP than 127.0.0.1 does not change anything.

> http://127.0.0.1:8095/geoserver/nurc/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&layers=nurc:Img_Sample&time=2018-08-15/2018-09-03&info_format=application/json&BBOX=-523.3886718750001,18.97902595325528,-406.14257812500006,69.3493386397765&FEATURE_COUNT=5&HEIGHT=890&WIDTH=1334&query_layers=nurc:Img_Sample&SRS=EPSG:4326&buffer=15&X=1127&Y=415

This was working in an older version (from 2017 - so maybe 2.11 ?, or did the browsers checks change ?)

From Chrome :

`Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8095
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`

Response Headers :

`Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length: 20
Server: Jetty(9.2.13.v20150730)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`

`!Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36`

From the console :

`
zone.js:2224 OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:8095/geoserver/nurc/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&layers=nurc:Img_Sample&time=2018-08-15/2018-09-03&info_format=application/json&BBOX=-523.3886718750001,18.97902595325528,-406.14257812500006,69.3493386397765&FEATURE_COUNT=5&HEIGHT=890&WIDTH=1334&query_layers=nurc:Img_Sample&SRS=EPSG:4326&buffer=15&X=1127&Y=415 403 (Forbidden)

zone.js:2224 OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:8095/geoserver/nurc/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&layers=nurc:Img_Sample&time=2018-08-15/2018-09-03&info_format=application/json&BBOX=-523.3886718750001,18.97902595325528,-406.14257812500006,69.3493386397765&FEATURE_COUNT=5&HEIGHT=890&WIDTH=1334&query_layers=nurc:Img_Sample&SRS=EPSG:4326&buffer=15&X=1127&Y=415 403 (Forbidden)

Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8095/geoserver/nurc/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&layers=nurc:Img_Sample&time=2018-08-15/2018-09-03&info_format=application/json&BBOX=-523.3886718750001,18.97902595325528,-406.14257812500006,69.3493386397765&FEATURE_COUNT=5&HEIGHT=890&WIDTH=1334&query_layers=nurc:Img_Sample&SRS=EPSG:4326&buffer=15&X=1127&Y=415: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.

01:00:35.526 vendor.dll.js:8 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}

`

Any ideas what the issue is here ?

Comment: Are you using jetty or tomcat?

Comment: in windows this would be jetty, as the startup.bat for 2.14RC is : <br/>   `call "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe" %MARLIN_ENABLER% -DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.13.2\data_dir" -Xmx512m -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=geoserver -Djetty.base="C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.14-RC" -Djetty.logs="C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.14-RC\logs" -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.14-RC\start.jar" --module=http jetty.port=8095`

Comment: to enable cors i followed this guide (http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html#enable-cors)  <br> basically edit webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml and uncomment whatever is there for CORS, as this changes for the older versions

Comment: Did you add the cors jar too?

Comment: with 2.14RC it is already in the geoserver 2.14RC\lib directory, with 2.10 i copied one from the net with the matching revision. There are no error messages during startup, so it should be using them.

Comment: in start.ini the module servlets is also enabled

Comment: So ... is CORS broken in geoserver ? should i file a bugreport ?

Comment: GeoServer doesn't have anything to do with CORS - this is entirely a jetty issue.

Comment: so is the version of jetty used in geoserver broken ? Or is there something else missing in the configuration ?

Comment: No one else has ever reported a problem so I suspect you have misconfigured it some how.

Comment: i started every time from a fresh geoserver installation, i posted all my configuration changes, so this should be trivial for someone else to check, right ? So probably i *should* post it to the bugtracker. What do you think ? Any other way to find out what is happening here ? if really needed i can make a trivial angular app with a big button which just does the CORS call, so they/you have a simple test case.

Comment: The GeoServer community will not care about your issue it has nothing to do with GeoServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Ian suspected this was not a problem with Geoserver 
but with another part of our program.

We are using JHipster and Angular - 
on the Angular side we have a HttpInterceptor which handles Authentication etc.

We had this enabled for all requests -

- so it cloned the request (HttpRequest.clone),

  added the JWT Token

  and then let the Angular HTTP-pipeline continue.

This was apparently enough to trip up the OPTIONS request.

I am still not sure why this only affected the WMS GetFeatureInfo request, we could display a map in leaflet without problems. (well leaflet probably didn't go through the angular http pipeline )

Answer (score 2):

Add the following in web.xml file under cross-origin filter-name

```
<init-param>
       <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
       <param-value>*</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
       <param-value>GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT,HEAD</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
       <param-value>origin, content-type, accept, authorization</param-value>
   </init-param>
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Some explanation what your code does could be helpful for other users, maybe you could expand your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem when I wanted to view a WMS layer using *Cesium Ion* or *Mapbox* library in a React app. The layer required authentication (i.e, basic authentication), so I had to pass `Authorization` header with my `Cesium.Resource`. So, preflight requests before the actual `GET` request was sent and they were rejected due to *CORS policy*.

It is said in CORS Specifications that preflight requests must be rejected if any of submitted header does not match the allowed *CORS headers*. The default configuration of the CorsFilter `cors.allowed.headers` (including mine) does not include the `Authorization` header that is sent with the request ([Link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter)). However, I made an update to the `cors.allowed.headers` filter setting to include acceptance of the `authorization` header, resulting in a successful preflight request:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```